# SQL invalid identifier and ambiguousy defined alias

Tags: sql, oracle, join, alias

The goal is to give back ucstomer_id, last_name, room_number, and the number of times a customer has stayed (aliased as stay_count). For some reason, I keep having trouble with the stay_count and it gives me an "ORA-00904: "STAY_COUNT": invalid identifier" or a "column ambiguously defined" for one of the columns

```
SELECT c.customer_id, 
c.last_name, 
    rm.room_number, 
    count(r.reservation_id) AS stay_count
FROM customer c
    INNER JOIN reservation r
        ON c.customer_id = r.customer_id
    INNER JOIN reservation_details rd
        ON r.reservation_id = rd.reservation_id
    INNER JOIN room rm
        ON rd.room_id = rm.room_id
WHERE stay_count > 1 AND rm.location_id = '1'
ORDER BY stay_count;
```

I've changed the code so many times, I don't know what's wrong. The conditions are that the customer has more than one stay and that it was in location_id  = 1.

Comment: That's because `stay_count` is defined / derived in the `SELECT` list.  The `WHERE` clause has access to the result of the `FROM` clause.  That column isn't generated in the rows produced by the `FROM` clause.  You can use a derived table or CTE term to derive the new column and then refer to that column in an outer or subsequent CTE term or query expression.  `SELECT ... FROM (SELECT expression AS stay_count ...) t WHERE t.stay_count > 1 ...`.  Also be careful of your use of expressions which are not functionally dependent on the `GROUP BY` terms.  Your `COUNT` invokes `GROUP BY` behavior.

Comment: If questions are about Oracle SQL then please tag them with [tag:oracle] and [tag:sql], not [tag:oracle-sqldeveloper] which is a desktop database browsing and editing application.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a GROUP BY statement.
If you want to filter on aggregate values then you need to put them in a HAVING clause, rather than a WHERE clause - though you still need the WHERE clause for any non-aggregate column filters